# When $Q(\alpha)=\int_B |f(x) - \alpha| \, dx$ is minimal?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, harmonic-analysis

I've been asked to prove (or find a counterexample) that the quantity $$Q(\alpha)=\int_B |f(x) - \alpha| \, dx$$ is always minimal when $\alpha=\bar{\alpha} = \frac{1}{|B|} \int_B f(x) \, dx$ ($|\cdot|$ is the *Lebesgue measure*), where $f \in L^1 _{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $B$ is a fixed ball.

Actually I couldn't say so much. I've just noticed that the function $Q : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is *Lipschitz continuous* with $\text{Lip}(Q) \le |B|$; moreover using the *triangle inequality* and the *reverse triangle inequality* I've obtained that $$\left|\int_B |f(x) - \gamma | \, dx - \int_B |f(x) -\bar{\alpha}| \, dx \right| \le \int_B |f(x) -  \gamma | \, dx $$which leads to  $$ \int_B |f(x) -\bar{\alpha}| \, dx  \le 2 \int_B |f(x) -  \gamma | \, dx \quad \forall \, \gamma \in \mathbb{R}. $$ Furthermore in a compact $K\subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $\bar{\alpha} \in K$ we would have $$ \int_B |f(x) -  \gamma_{\min} | \, dx \le \int_B |f(x) -\bar{\alpha}| \, dx  \le 2 \int_B |f(x) -  \gamma_{\min} | \, dx. $$

I weakly suspect that this can be proved, but I couldn't do anything more.

Do you have any idea/hint?

Comment: Actually $Q(\alpha)$ is minimal at the median, not the mean, that is, when $$\mathrm{Leb}\{x\in B\mid f(x)>\alpha\}=\mathrm{Leb}\{x\in B\mid f(x)<\alpha\}.$$

Comment: May you give me an hint on how to prove that?

Comment: Anyway the function $f(x) = 1/\sqrt{|x|} \in L^1_{\text{loc}} ([-1,1])$ should be a valid counterexample. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: For almost every $t$, $$\frac{d}{d\alpha}|t-\alpha|=\mathbf 1_{t<\alpha}-\mathbf 1_{t>\alpha}.$$